# conditional mutate by dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, substr

I want to create a new column in my dataset that: i) drop the last 1 character if the word itself starts with "vi"; and ii) drop the last 2 characters if the word itself does not start with "vi". I know how to work on that in R, like below:

```
iris$Species <- as.character(iris$Species)
iris$Species_mod <- substr(iris$Species,
                           1,
                           ifelse(grepl('^vi',iris$Species),
                                  nchar(iris$Species)-1,
                                  nchar(iris$Species)-2))
```

But I have a hard time in deciphering the `mutate`, `if_else` and `matches` in dplyr. Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `case_when` from `tidyverse`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same idea, except you explicitly need to convert your factor to a string

```
iris = mutate(iris, Species_mod = substr(Species, 1, nchar(as.character(Species)) - 
    ifelse(grepl('^vi', Species), 1, 2)))
```

Comment: Not working, it returned an error: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: 'nchar()' requires a character vector.`

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like:

```
iris %>%
  mutate(Species = as.character(Species))  %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(species2 = case_when(
    Species == 'vi%' ~ substr(Species, 0, nchar(Species) - 1),
    Species != 'vi%' ~ substr(Species, 0, nchar(Species) - 2)
  ))
```